# I am having a query regarding snack bar in neutrinos studio

Tags: angular-material, neutrinos-platform

While adding **snack bar** to my component in neutrinos studio,**from where** should we need to **import that?**

Answer (score 0):

I got your query regarding snack-bar, you need to import the `NSnackbarService` from `neutrinos-seed-services` in your respective `.ts` file.

Import Statement: `import { NSnackbarService } from 'neutrinos-seed-services';`